# t test or chi square

Tags: chi-squared-test

1. What is the difference between t test and chi square?
2. Which test to be used for my below hypothesis and why?
   "Is there a difference between gender (male/female) on voting behavior?
3. Can I use both chi square and t test?

Comment: My guess is that this is being downvoted because there is no visible research effort. These techniques usually appear in elementary courses and introductory texts.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference between t test and chi square?

The t-test is used for comparing means of two groups; chi-square tests are mainly used for testing various hypotheses relating to count data, like goodness of fit or independence (but can also be used for several other purposes)

> Which test to be used for my below hypothesis and why? "Is there a difference between gender (male/female) on voting behavior?

It's impossible to tell without specifying how "voting behavior" is measured. If we're talking about the proportion of a sample of voters of each gender who will choose a particular candidate, the answer is likely to differ from whether it's (say) how long someone spends deliberating before actually voting. Both are arguably aspects of voting behavior that someone might choose to compare for males and females.

> Can I use both chi square and t test?

Normally you would use one test, whichever is the best suited to the actual hypothesis and data.